# Tomcat suddenly shutdown

Tags: tomcat7, shutdown, http-status-code-503

Tomcat randomly stops receiving requests and returns **error 503**.

Im running a tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 12.04 TLS updated.

In the apache error log you can see the following trace:

```
[Wed Mar 04 09:36:27 2015] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
[Wed Mar 04 09:36:27 2015] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Mar 04 09:36:27 2015] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
[Wed Mar 04 09:36:27 2015] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Mar 04 09:36:27 2015] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
[Wed Mar 04 09:36:27 2015] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
[Wed Mar 04 09:36:27 2015] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
```

There is no trace of error in any of the tomcat log files (catalina) :S

That is not caused by memory leaks Head Space or Java Head Space, because i cause these problems and error traces appear in the log files (besides, I reviewed the code and there is no `system.exit()` on any file).

I'm pretty confused and i can't understand what is happening!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem once, please have a look at my blog post
http://www.77dev.com/2014/07/tomcat-randomly-shuts-down-without-any-logs.html

Comment: This morning I have been looking for information, and coincidentally I read your post ;-) , unfortunately I have nothing related to the tail -f, but thanks anyway!